# Is there an advantage to using an otherwise synchronous function inside a Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

Say I have a synchronous function like this:

```
function sumTotal(items) {
  return items.reduce((total, item) => item.price + total)
}
```

And it is used after a Promise.all containing some asynchronous API calls within this 'checkout' function

```
function checkout(items) {
  return Promise.all([
    getLatestOffers(),
    getCustomerDetails('johndoe@gmail.com')
  ]).then(([offers, details]) => {
    return { offers, details, total: sumTotal(items) }
  });
}
```

Is there be any advantage, performance wise or other, to changing the sumTotal function to return a promise and calling it in the Promise.all like this?

```
function checkOut(items) {
  return Promise.all([
    getLatestOffers(),
    getCustomerDetails('johndoe@gmail.com'),
    sumTotal(items)
  ]).then(([offers, details, total]) => {
    return { offers, details, total }
  });
}
```

Comment: Biggest difference is timing. In the first version `sumTotal(items)` is calculated in the same event turn as `getLatestOffers()` and `getCustomerDetails('johndoe@gmail.com')` calls are made. In the second version `sumTotal(items)` is calculated in the event turn when `getLatestOffers()` and `getCustomerDetails('johndoe@gmail.com')` deliver their asynchronously derived results. There *could* be a differnce between the two values and there's no unique answer to which one might be the more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Either method works. Because `sumTotal` is synchronous, it won't matter in most cases. The only time it *might* matter is if `items` is an unreasonably huge array, and iterating over it takes a not-insignificant amount of CPU time - in which case, it would be better to call `sumTotal` with `Promise.all` so that it can resolve *immediately* once the promises resolve, rather than having to wait for an expensive operation *after* the other promises resolve.

But, keep in mind that `Promise.all` accepts non-Promises as well: there's no need to convert `sumTotal` to something that returns a `Promise`.

Also, if `items` is an array of objects with a `price` property, make sure to provide `reduce` with an initial value, else you might end up with something like `[Object object]102030` for your `total`:

```js
const somethingAsync = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500, 'foo'));

function sumTotal(items) {
  return items.reduce((total, item) => item.price + total, 0)
}
function checkOut(items) {
  return Promise.all([
    somethingAsync(),
    somethingAsync('johndoe@gmail.com'),
    sumTotal(items)
  ]).then(([offers, details, total]) => (
    { offers, details, total }
  ));
}

console.log('start');
checkOut([{ price: 10 }, { price: 20 }])
  .then(output => console.log(output));
```